# How to make a loop execute artisan command with date paremeter?

Tags: laravel-4

I had set up an artisan command like `php artisan db:update 2014-08-01 2014-12-16`

but it would cause memory exhausted and cause a php fatal error.

so I need to manually execute

`php artisan db:update 2014-08-01 2014-08-01`

`php artisan db:update 2014-08-02 2014-08-02`....

Is there any simple method that could execute loop between two dates?

Thanks

Comment: First thing that comes to mind: a shell/batch script

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a cron job to do the updating, at specified intervals.

The one package, i recommend for this purpose is: https://github.com/Indatus/dispatcher

You can execute it through `artisan` or schedule the job directly from your php class.